# FlatList swipe omnidirectional

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I've a bug with FlatList horizontal. Sometime, my scroll was run on multiverse.

This is my code:

```
  <FlatList
     data={products}
     keyExtractor={item => item.id + ''}
     horizontal
     showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
     renderItem={({ item }) => <ProductItem item={item} />}
     contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: scale(15) }}
     style={{ marginTop: scale(12) }}
  />
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide some of your code in the question. For the best answer share your code with flatlist element.

Comment: Sorry. I have added my code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.